# Project/Package Explorer like plug-in in RCP

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, explorer

I've been researching online on how to create my own project explorer using Eclipse RCP and SWT and was wondering if there is an existing plug-in available?

I tried copying the example from a book about adding org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer
but it doesn't exist in my list of packages so I tried searching for similar errors online and this is what I found:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=351875

Any suggestions?

part of the code: (plugin.xml)

```
<perspectiveExtension
        targetID="SampleTwo.perspective">
     <view 
           id="SampleTwo.view"
           minimized="false"
           ratio="0.5"
           relationship="left"
           relative="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer">
     </view>
     <view
           id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer"
           minimized="false"
           ratio="0.5"
           relationship="right"
           relative="SampleTwo.view">
     </view>
  </perspectiveExtension>
```

Answer (score 0):

this will help you http://scribbledideas.blogspot.com/